# How to fix syntax error when escaping table name?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE 'test'.'sensor' (

'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
'time' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
'value' VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL
 );
```

This is my code which I entered in phpMyAdmin. And when I pressed go I got the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'.'sensor' (
>   'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>   'time' TIMES' at line 1

I have tried changing some statements but couldn't get the error.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses backticks to escape identifiers, single and double quotes for strings.

In this case you should do:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`sensor` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`value` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL
 );
```

It's worth noting that backticks are only strictly required when your name conflicts with a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and even then many are only relevant in a specific context. Terms like `ORDER` or `SELECT` always need to be escaped, so using them for columns or table names is best avoided. Likewise, `TIME` is also a column type, so you may want to pick a different name.

Additionally the `TIMESTAMP` column type is quite limited, values can only exist in the range of 1970 to 2038, so using it is not recommended. The `DATETIME` type by comparison has a range of years 1000 to 9999, more than adequate for most needs. There's a few [other quirks of `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) worth keeping in mind, too, like automatic UTC conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Check that which version of php and MySQL u are using i have face this problem but solved after research . this query is working on MySQL 5.5 or newer
and MariaDB 5.5 or newer

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE Ghee(
    country_code char(1) NOT NULL default '',
description varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (country_code)
)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)